# R subtract string from text and create 4 new variables base on the subtracts

Tags: r

I have the following data in R:

Product_description

```
Can Al SOL 355ml Exp 2014
Can Al 7UP 330ml STD Vintage 50s 2015
ZZ_Can Al HEINEKEN Light 500ml 473 US 13
ZZ_Can Al TECATE 710ml MX 2009
Can Al SOL 355ml Carnaval 2012
Can Al HEINEKEN 330ml 4x6 NL 1508
ZZ_Can Al CARTA BLANCA Light 355ml 2010
Can Al CARTA BLANCA 355ml CL/CO 2012
Can Al STRONGBOW Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO
```

and I would like to create 4 columns splitting the content in 4 new variables:
Brand, Type, Capacity and Description.

I would like to get the following (not sure if this will be clear without columns):

```
Brand   type    Capacity    Description
SOL     355ml   Exp 2014
7UP     330ml    STD Vintage 50s 2015
HEINEKEN    Light   500ml   473 US 13
TECATE      710ml   MX 2009
SOL     355ml   Carnaval 2012
HEINEKEN        330ml   4x6 NL 1508
CARTA BLANCA    Light   355ml   2010
CARTA BLANCA        355ml   CL/CO 2012
STRONGBOW   Red Berries     400BG/GR/RO
```

So far I've used the gsub function but still not getting what I want.

```
data$Descrip <- gsub("Can Al", " ", data$Materialdescription)
data$Descrip <- gsub("[S]", " ", data$Materialdescription)
data$brand <-gsub("[a-z][A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z][a-z]+", '', data$Descrip)
data$brand <-gsub("\\d", '', data$brand)

x <- regmatches(data$brand, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", data$brand))
data$dim <- as.numeric(unlist(x))
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Please, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Could you possibly line up the desired result a little better so people can easily tell how the data should be split.

Comment: Can you add `dput(Product_description)` for better reproducibility?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the data is contained in a text file, the "brand" is always written uppercase, and the "type" is never written uppercase.
Usually "type" and "description" are separated by "capacity". But in

> Can Al STRONGBOW Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO

for example there is no capacity. For such cases the function `generateTable` has an optional argument `knownTypes`. If "brand" is followed by a string that matches one of the known types, it is used as the "type". Otherwise a warning is given and everything is put to the "description".

```
data <- readLines(path)

#=====================================================================

generateTable <- function( data, knownTypes = NULL )
{
  knownTypes.expr  <- paste("[ ]*(",paste(knownTypes,collapse="|"),")[ ]+",sep="")

  data <- gsub( "(.*Can Al[ ]+)","",data)

  brand.pos <- regexpr( "([A-Z0-9]+( ))+", data )

  if (!all(brand.pos==1)){ stop("'brand' missing.")}

  brand <- mapply("substr", data, brand.pos, brand.pos+attr(brand.pos,"match.length")-2 )
  names(brand) <- NULL

  data <- mapply("sub",paste(brand,"[ ]*",sep=""),"",data)

  capacity.pos <- regexpr( "[0-9]+ml", data )

  if (!is.null(knownTypes))
  {
    lastAttempt <- regexpr(knownTypes.expr,data)

    capacity.pos[which(lastAttempt==1)] <-
      attr(lastAttempt,"match.length")[which(lastAttempt==1)] + 1
  }


  for (i in which(capacity.pos<0))
  {
    warning( sprintf("No 'capacity' found in line %i. Separation of 'type' and 'description' impossible.",i),
             call.=FALSE )
  }

  capacity <- mapply("substr", data, capacity.pos, capacity.pos+attr(capacity.pos,"match.length")-1 )
  names(capacity) <- NULL

  type <- mapply("substr", data, 1, capacity.pos-1 )
  names(type) <- NULL

  data <- mapply("sub",type,"",data)
  data <- mapply("sub",capacity,"",data)

  description <- mapply("sub","[ ]+","",paste(" ",data))
  names(description) <- NULL

  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  Tbl <- data.frame( Brand       = brand,
                     Type        = type,
                     Capacity    = capacity,
                     Description = description )

  Tbl <- sub("( )*\n","",apply(Tbl,1:2,paste,"\n",sep=""))

  return ( Tbl )
}
```

Examples:

```
> generateTable(data)
      Brand          Type    Capacity Description              
 [1,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Exp 2014"               
 [2,] "7UP"          ""      "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"   
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light" "500ml"  "473 US 13"              
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""      "710ml"  "MX 2009"                
 [5,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"          
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""      "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"            
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light" "355ml"  "2010"                   
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""      "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"             
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    ""      ""       "Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO"
Warning message:
No 'capacity' found in line 9. Separation of 'type' and 'description' impossible. 
> generateTable(data,"Red Berries")
      Brand          Type          Capacity Description           
 [1,] "SOL"          ""            "355ml"  "Exp 2014"            
 [2,] "7UP"          ""            "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light"       "500ml"  "473 US 13"           
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""            "710ml"  "MX 2009"             
 [5,] "SOL"          ""            "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"       
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""            "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"         
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light"       "355ml"  "2010"                
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""            "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"          
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    "Red Berries" ""       "400BG/GR/RO"         
> generateTable(data,"Red")
      Brand          Type    Capacity Description           
 [1,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Exp 2014"            
 [2,] "7UP"          ""      "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light" "500ml"  "473 US 13"           
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""      "710ml"  "MX 2009"             
 [5,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"       
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""      "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"         
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light" "355ml"  "2010"                
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""      "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"          
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    "Red"   ""       "Berries 400BG/GR/RO" 
> generateTable(data,"Berries")
      Brand          Type    Capacity Description              
 [1,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Exp 2014"               
 [2,] "7UP"          ""      "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"   
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light" "500ml"  "473 US 13"              
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""      "710ml"  "MX 2009"                
 [5,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"          
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""      "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"            
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light" "355ml"  "2010"                   
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""      "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"             
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    ""      ""       "Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO"
Warning message:
No 'capacity' found in line 9. Separation of 'type' and 'description' impossible. 
> generateTable(data,c("Red Berries","Heavy"))
      Brand          Type          Capacity Description           
 [1,] "SOL"          ""            "355ml"  "Exp 2014"            
 [2,] "7UP"          ""            "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light"       "500ml"  "473 US 13"           
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""            "710ml"  "MX 2009"             
 [5,] "SOL"          ""            "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"       
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""            "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"         
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light"       "355ml"  "2010"                
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""            "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"          
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    "Red Berries" ""       "400BG/GR/RO"         
> generateTable(data,c("Light","Heavy"))
      Brand          Type    Capacity Description              
 [1,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Exp 2014"               
 [2,] "7UP"          ""      "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"   
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light" "500ml"  "473 US 13"              
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""      "710ml"  "MX 2009"                
 [5,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"          
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""      "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"            
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light" "355ml"  "2010"                   
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""      "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"             
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    ""      ""       "Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO"
Warning message:
No 'capacity' found in line 9. Separation of 'type' and 'description' impossible. 
> generateTable(data,c("Heavy"))
      Brand          Type    Capacity Description              
 [1,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Exp 2014"               
 [2,] "7UP"          ""      "330ml"  "STD Vintage 50s 2015"   
 [3,] "HEINEKEN"     "Light" "500ml"  "473 US 13"              
 [4,] "TECATE"       ""      "710ml"  "MX 2009"                
 [5,] "SOL"          ""      "355ml"  "Carnaval 2012"          
 [6,] "HEINEKEN"     ""      "330ml"  "4x6 NL 1508"            
 [7,] "CARTA BLANCA" "Light" "355ml"  "2010"                   
 [8,] "CARTA BLANCA" ""      "355ml"  "CL/CO 2012"             
 [9,] "STRONGBOW"    ""      ""       "Red Berries 400BG/GR/RO"
Warning message:
No 'capacity' found in line 9. Separation of 'type' and 'description' impossible. 
>
```

Comment: Hi mra68, there is not a list of Brands or Types a priory. With the syntax shown above I was able to extract the brands since all of them are in uppercase (apart from maybe two brands). The difficulty I have is to identify the type, but this is always between the brand and the capacity (which almost always have the same format xxxml). So I guess the trick here is to extract the capacity and them we will have a list of brands and capacity and everything that is between brand and capacity is the type and everything that is after capacity is description.

Comment: I will edit my answer such that the list of brands is no longer needed. If the brand is really always uppercase and the type is never uppercase, that's no problem. But how do you want to seperate type and description in the last line? There is no capacity to separate them. An R script will not be able to decide whether "Red Berries" belongs to the type or to the description.

Comment: The list of brands is gone.

Comment: I've edited my answer again. The list of types is now optional. That's perhaps the best one can do if the given data is incomplete.